# How do I disable typing symbols like ç when holding the option key and pressing a key?

Tags: keyboard

I just want the option key to trigger keyboard shortcuts when combined with other keys (<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for example) instead of the `ç`used by Spanish and Portuguese speakers ... I've read on here that one can use Karabiner-elements to remap the key but have no clue how.

Comment: Apple dedicates the option level for typing special characters needed in languages other than English.  In the long run, you are better off using Command or Control for keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: It’s not a random symbol. It’s a modified c, modified by adding a cedilla.